# Abstract tree vs parser tree

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit

I need your opinions in order to choose the best alternative between the choice of to generate an parser tree (ST) or to generate an abstract syntax tree (AST). The is the context:

I want to parse a language like C (just a subset of C with some changes to make it more pseudocode-oriented), but not in order to translate it in other output language/file, but to execute its sentences for animating its execution process (I use Qt to draw). A feature of this C subset is it enables nested scopes. My doubt related to my election between ST and AST arises from the symbol table. The general idea is (using Boost.spirit):

1. Parsing a source code file by means of a custom Boost.spirit parser.
2. The semantic actions produces a Syntax Tree, just a copy of the source code's syntax tree (or also, a copy of the Boost.spirit's internal syntax tree, but with my own classes and structures). Thus, there isn't a AST.
3. With this ST in the hand, the program read this syntax tree in a top-down direction as following:

   1. Execute the first sentence.
   2. Upload the symbol table with the new (outcome of the sentence) values.
   3. Save the actual state of the symbol table in a program state stack.
   4. To 3.1 until the ST is completely processed.
   5. Animate the algorithm reading and drawing the program state stack.

Two reasonings:

1. If I work with a AST, I lost, after parsing, information about variable declarations, its types and so on. Thus, I have to work with the symbol table by means of the semantic actions of the parser, complicating the parser writing and understanding. Moreover, I have to work all the time with a symbol table with all variables, irrespective of the actual scope (if I'm in the scope i, only need the scopes i, i-1, ...., 1; not all the scopes throughout the algorithm). This spends memory.
2. I only need, in my program state stack, variables of the actual and previous scopes, for not complicating the understandability of the algorithm through the animation. If I work with a ST, I have to delete all symbols I don't need before save it in the stack. This spends time.
3. A static symbol table with control scopes is more difficult to design and use than a dynamic symbol table. A static symbol table must have an identifier (for example) for each scope, and to relate each node of the tree with each identifier. A dynamic symbol table works easier because if I'm in the scope i, only need two "vectors" (perhaps a double-queue and a stack):

   - A container (double-queue?) with symbols and its related information: the last variable in the container is the nearest declared variable.
   - A container (stack) of integers, showing the beginning (index of the double-queue) of each scope.

   For example, for the scope i:

   - Container 1: [x y z x a b z f a z]
   - Container 2: [0 3 6 8]

   If I leave the scope i, only I have to erase the last integer and the symbols from position 8 up to the end. The tree keep unmodified.
4. Due to I have to execute each sentence in execution time, a ST facilitates my execution.

Two question:

1. Which is better then?
2. Exist any form to extract the internal tree of Spirit or customizing it in order to not copy it?

Comment: You have just reminded me of what I lost (almost) when I had to move to C# :|

Comment: This would become remotely answerable if you had a grammar and a basic implementation here. Also, what does it mean to "Animate the algorithm reading and drawing the program state stack". I have a hunch that description already pre-supposes a particular implementation.

Comment: What I see here now is "Not a real question" (because there are no concrete requirements, only loose thoughts) and "Too localized" (because the 'implied requirements' (animation(?), specific scoping ideas) are unlikely to be relevant to others in the future.

Comment: It is a theoretic/design question with a little of context. It isn't an implementation problem. Any book about compilers speak about AST, because the custom creation of a parser tree is (it is said in this books) a lost of sources due to the program create two times a parser tree (the parser's tree itself and the copy you generate). But I ask if this books have reason for contexts like this (an interprete) I think the question is clear and relevant.

Comment: @sehe The animation isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is an abstract semantic graph (ASG) that represents the *semantics* (as opposed to the syntax) of a program. What you can do is:

1. Parse the source to an AST, then
2. convert the AST into an ASG, and finally
3. walk the ASG to execute the actual code.

Also, I'd say that you **can** indeed build an AST which is no *too* abstract; for example, I'm currently building my own scripting language interpreter, and the AST will contain the variable names (this is useful for debugging the parser/interpreter and the parsed program itself as well).

Comment: In fact, for 'animation purposes' (whatever the requirements look like) I'd simply store the source iterator ranges with the relevant tokens. Sort of like 'debug information' on binaries, but on the parse tree